# SQL Server reduce on disk size

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in production and need to reduce the on disk size of the database. I followed the instructions to shrink the file but the results was a bit surprising.

Sorry for the lots of numbers here but I do not know how to express the problem any better.

Database containing only one table with 11,634,966 rows.

The table structure as follow I just changed the column names

```
id bigint not null    8 -- the primary key (clustered index)
F1 int not null       4
F2 int not null       4
F3 int not null       4
F4 datetime not null  8
F5 int not nul        4
F6 int not null       4
F7 int not null       4
F8 xml                ?
F9 uniqueidentifier   16
F10 int               4
F11 datetime not null 8
```

Excluding the XML field I calculate that the data size will be 68 bytes per row.

I ran a query against the database finding the min, max and avg size of the xml field F8

Showing the following:

```
min :   625 bytes
max : 81782 bytes
avg :  5321 bytes
```

The on disk file is 108G big after shrinking the database.

This translate to the following

```
108G / 11.6M records = 9283 bytes per row
- 5321 bytes per row (Avg of XML)
= 3962 bytes per row
- 68 (data size of other fields in row)
= 3894 bytes per row. (must be overhead)
```

but this mean that the overhead is 41.948%

Is this to be expected? and is there anything that I can do to reduce the 108G disk size.

BTW there is only one clustered index on the table.

And I am using SQL Server 2008 (SP3)

Comment: Your missing fillfactor and the fact you do have a nullable fields (F8, F9 & F10), which account for bit field for tracking nulls.  You have an ~11M row table with only a single index?  You do also realize, shrinking space is going to kill performance, due to the non-optimal, "compressed" layout of pages that will be ondisk?

Comment: Also, since you didn't provide your calculation script, you will want to evaluate its accuracy against the MSFT recommendation for estimating table size reference out of MSDN - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175991(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: here is the SQL I used
select
 min(cast(len(cast(F8 as varchar(max))) as bigint)),
 max(cast(len(cast(F8 as varchar(max))) as bigint)),
 avg(cast(len(cast(F8 as varchar(max))) as bigint))
from TheTable with (nolock)

Comment: And fill factor is 0
SELECT Fill_Factor
FROM Sys.Indexes
WHERE Object_id=object_id('TheTable')
AND name IS NOT NULL

Comment: The Reason I need to shrink the database is as follow. I am running out of disk space on the server. This is the largest database on the server ocupying 108 of the 250G available. this database cought my eye because of it's size and only one table and 11M rows. It may well be that nothing can be done to it. but 41% overhead per row sound high to me. if I can get that down to 20% it should save a good 15 to 20 G of disk space. I know it is not a long term solution but will buy me some breathing space. (Final solution will be to move database to better server)